# Create a grid from array X and Y and store them in data.frame/tibble

Tags: r, contour, tibble

I wish to create contour of P = f(X,Y), where

```
X <- seq(-10, 10, 0.1)
Y <- seq(-10, 10, 0.1)
```

How do I create a grid of points and store them in data.frame/tibble of X and Y?
such that for each value of X, Y ranges from -10 to 10.
So that I can calculate P for all combinations of X and Y to draw contour.

Thanks

Comment: `expand.grid(X, Y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(X, Y)
```